# SearchView and Recyclerview, showing right cards, but at the same time others are removed permanently

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement searchview. It works somehow, but the problem is that after you start typing it is one-way street. You get the info but if you delete text, you won't get the result as it was in the beginning. I'm working with cardviews. 
Marker is a model(gettitle etc.)

My Adapter:

```
public class AdapterRestavracije extends                      
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRestavracije.ViewHolderRestavracije> {
ArrayList<Marker> arrayList;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private VolleySingleton mVolleySingleton;
Context context;

public AdapterRestavracije(Context context, ArrayList<Marker> models) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsIstance();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<Marker>(models);
   // this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
}



public void setRestaurants(ArrayList<Marker> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    notifyItemChanged(0, arrayList.size());
}


@Override
public ViewHolderRestavracije onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurants_rview, parent, false);
    ViewHolderRestavracije viewHolder = new ViewHolderRestavracije(view);


    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderRestavracije holder, int position) {

    Marker currentRest = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(currentRest.getTitle());
    holder.address.setText(currentRest.getAddress());
    holder.placilo.setText(currentRest.getValue_of_charge() + " €");
    holder.oddaljenost.setText(currentRest.getOddaljenost());
    holder.idrestavracije.setText(currentRest.getId());
    try {
        holder.ratingBarOverall.setRating(Float.parseFloat(currentRest.getOverallRating()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        holder.ratingBarOverall.setRating(0);
    }

    Log.d("RESTAVRACIJEEEEE", currentRest.getTitle());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

class ViewHolderRestavracije extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name, oddaljenost, address, textPlacilo, placilo, idrestavracije;
    private RatingBar ratingBarOverall;
    private int id;
    public View view;

    public ViewHolderRestavracije(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;


        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameRestaurant);
        oddaljenost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOddaljenost);
        address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        textPlacilo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDoplacilo);
        placilo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDoplaciloEvri);
        idrestavracije = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idrestavracije);


        ratingBarOverall = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingOverallRestavracije);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //id = getAdapterPosition();

                //Log.d("CLICKED", idrestavracije.getText().toString() + "");
                //Log.d("CLICKED", name.getText().toString() + "");

                String idrest = idrestavracije.getText().toString();

                //   Log.d("CLICKED", intid + "");

                //   Intent i = new Intent(context, RestaurantActivity.class);
                //  i.putExtra("ID_rest", intid);
                //    context.startActivity(i);

                Intent i = new Intent(context, RestaurantActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("ID_rest", idrest);

                i.putExtras(bundle);

                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

}

////PRIPRAVA ZA SEARCH//////

public void animateTo(ArrayList<Marker> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}
private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(ArrayList<Marker> newModels) {
    for (int i = arrayList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final Marker model = arrayList.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}
private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(ArrayList<Marker> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final Marker model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!arrayList.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(ArrayList<Marker> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final Marker model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = arrayList.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public Marker removeItem(int position) {
    final Marker model = arrayList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, Marker model) {
    arrayList.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final Marker model = arrayList.remove(fromPosition);
    arrayList.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}

////PRIPRAVA ZA SEARCH//////
```

}

MY FRAGMENT:

```
---OTHER CODE----
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listRestaurants);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    // recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    listRestaurants = new ArrayList<Marker>();

    jsonRequest(latitude, longitude);

    adapterRestavracije = new AdapterRestavracije(getActivity(),listRestaurants);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRestavracije);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu2, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView sv = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
   // Utils.LogDebug("Submitted: "+query);
    Log.d("Clicked: ", query);

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
  //  Utils.LogDebug("Changed: " + newText);
    final ArrayList<Marker> filteredModelList = filter(listRestaurants, query);
    adapterRestavracije.animateTo(filteredModelList);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    //Log.d("Query Changed: ", query);
    return false;
}

private ArrayList<Marker> filter(ArrayList<Marker> listRestaurants, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final ArrayList<Marker> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    for (Marker model : listRestaurants) {
        final String text = model.getTitle().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

---OTHER CODE----
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, fixed the problem. The problem was that the arraylist wasn't declared as final. So now that i did that it works :).

Example:

before:

```
List<ExampleModel> mModels;
```

after:

```
private final List<ExampleModel> mModels;
```